# Woocommerce Product Title Selector

Tags: html, css, woocommerce, product, elementor

I am trying to change the font and size (in CSS) of the product title on our single product page developed with Woocommerce and Elementor. However, I cannot seem to find which selector to use in order to target the product title.

I have managed to find the correct one for the currency symbol and price, but somehow none of the usual selectors will work on the product title.

```
.product_title {
    font-size: 20px!important;
}

h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title {
    font-size: 20px!important;
}
```

etc.

Does anybody happen to know how best to proceed?

https://fursttedesco.com/the-bathrobe/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried? .wl-gradient-heading

```
.wl-gradient-heading {
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

**Before**
[image]
**After**
[image]